# Change status on promise status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to change the button text on the promise status using custom directive.

so here is the code of my custom directive

```
.directive('myDir',function(){
          return {
            scope: {
              myDir: '&',
              afterValue: '@',
              beforeValue:'@',
              ngDisable:'=',
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
              element[0].innerHTML=$scope.beforeValue;
              element.bind('click',function(){
                console.log(element);

                element[0].innerHTML=$scope.afterValue;
                element[0].className+="disabled";
                element[0].disabled='true'
                $scope.myDir();
                //success i would like to change the status here
              })
            }
          }

        })
```

and my controller

```
.controller('myCtrl',[function(){
          var vm = this;
          console.log("MYCTRL");
          vm.fun= function(){
            //promise running here
          }
        }])
```

and here is plnkr link : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Qj9GG2?p=templates/

I am unable to read success of promise  in directive.

Comment: I don't see that you're using a promise at all - Here's an working example with a promise - https://plnkr.co/edit/CamlTmSgjHlLJRf139G0. Let me know if it works and I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.then` to get the result of a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). In the example below I create a promise which will be resolved after 2 seconds. When it's resolved the directive will change the text on the button.

I create a promise with `$q`, but it's the same thing if you do an ajax-call:

```
  vm.fun= function(){
    //promise running here
    return $http.get('www.foo.org');
  }
```

```js
angular
        .module('myApp',[])
        .directive('myDir',function(){
          return {
            scope: {
              myDir: '&',
              afterValue: '@',
              beforeValue:'@',
              ngDisable:'=',
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
              element[0].innerHTML=$scope.beforeValue;
              element.bind('click',function(){                  
                element[0].innerHTML=$scope.afterValue;
                element[0].className+="disabled";
                element[0].disabled='true'
                $scope.myDir().then(function(){
                  //success i would like to change the status here  
                  // Change status here...
                  console.log('Callback from promise. Everything is fine.');
                  
                  element[0].disabled=false;
                  element[0].innerHTML = $scope.beforeValue;
                }, function(){
                    // Something went bad.
                    console.log('Callback from promise. Something went wrong.');
                });
                
              })
            }
          }
          
        })
        .controller('myCtrl',['$q', function($q){
          var vm = this;
          console.log("MYCTRL");
          vm.fun= function(){
            console.log('method called');
            // Create a promise here...
            var def = $q.defer();
            
            setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('done in controller');
              def.resolve();
              
              // You can also use reject if something went wrong.
              // def.reject();
            }, 2000)
            
            return def.promise;
          }
        }])
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" my-dir="$ctrl.fun()" after-value="Clicked" before-value="click" ng-disabled>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** based on comments:

> When user clicks on button it should change text and disable the
>   button and call invoke promise. the button text change and disable i
>   am doing it in directive and invoking the promise in controller.

This is what's happening in the line `$scope.myDir()`, altough you don't *invoke* a promise. You call a `function`, which in turn returns a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise). **How do you mean that the promise should be invoked?**

> next i want to depending of promise success or fail which is running
>   on controller i would like to change the text and make disable false.

This is what's happening under `.then()`. If `myDir()` was successful. Then the code will change the status back on the button. This is done in the directive, since it's only the directive that knows about the button. You have both a success and error callback from the promise.

Comment: That's nice one but, I have some operations to be executed in controller when promise is executed depending on success or fail. i would like to execute promise in controller rather than in custom directive.. :(

Comment: @Narengs - Could you rephrase your question? Which promise are you referring to? There's no promise in the directive?

Comment: let me give an example.
When user clicks on button it should change text and disable the button and call invoke promise. the button text change and disable i am doing it in directive and invoking the promise in controller.

next i want to depending of promise success or fail which is running on controller i would like to change the text and make disable false.

Comment: @Narengs - I've updated the answer, altough I'm not sure I understand what you're after.